# modulus in assembly

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, x86

I am learning assembly language.

Is there modulus operator in assembly? I know I can find the remainder using the formula Number= Divident * Divisor + Remainder.

I have heard when we use the DIV syntax the remainder is stored in one of the register?

**Edit 1 :** I am using Intel x86 Architecture and devloping it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DIV instruction returns the quotient in AX and the remainder in DX, on the x86 architecture.

Comment: i did bunch of research for this topic.. till i read your simple yet brilliant information (answer).. thank you so much @Delan Azabani

Comment: the registers used depends on the size of the operands. There are 8, 16, 32 or 64 bit divides in x86 and they use al, ax, eax or rax differently

Answer (score 1):

`al` <-- AX div source

`ah` <-- AX mod source

if size of source was a byte. `ah` contains the remainder.

`AX` <-- DX:AX div source

`DX` <-- DX:AX mod source

if size of source was a word. `DX` contains the remainder.