# Assembly division and modulo

Tags: assembly

```
LBACHS:
          xor     dx, dx                              ; prepare dx:ax for operation
          div     WORD [bpbSectorsPerTrack]           ; calculate (AX / WORD [bpbSectorsPerTrack]
          inc     dl                                  ; adjust for sector 0
          mov     BYTE [absoluteSector], dl
          xor     dx, dx                              ; prepare dx:ax for operation
          div     WORD [bpbHeadsPerCylinder]          ; calculate
          mov     BYTE [absoluteHead], dl             ;
          mov     BYTE [absoluteTrack], al            ;Quotient is returned in AL
          ret
```

I have two questions regarding this piece of code.

I thought `DIV` stores the results in AX not DL? Why would I increase the DL register?

How is modulos calculated? With DL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [modulus in assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511146/modulus-in-assembly). Any reference on x86 assembly will explain [what DIV does](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_72.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 16-bit `DIV` instruction divides the 32-bit value in DX:AX by a 16-bit number (from `[bpbSectorsPerTrack]` in your case); then stores the quotient in AX and the remainder in DX.

For your specific case, the value in DX:AX before the division is an LBA sector number. After the division, value in AX is `LBA / sectors_per_track` and the value in DX is `LBA % sectors_per_track = CHS_sector - 1`. *Note: For CHS the first sector is sector number 1 and not sector number 0, which is why there's an `inc` involved.*

For the second division, the value in DX:AX beforehand is `LBA / sectors_per_track`. After the division, value in AX is `(LBA / sectors_per_track) / heads_per_cylinder = cylinder` and the value in DX is `(LBA / sectors_per_track) % heads_per_cylinder = head`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering!
If AbsoluteSector = (LBA / sectors_per_track) + 1
Why is DL being stored in [AbsoluteSector]? Shouldn't it be AX + 1?

Comment: Nvm, I found out the reason. In the tutorial, the author did not mention that the sector number is equal to (LBA MOD sectors_per_track) + 1. He used a division sign.